# Nginx rule for redirection

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, webserver

I have below rule in Nginx to redirect particular url to new url

```
location /customer/my_info {
  proxy_pass http://example.com/abc;
}
```

This works fine. I also have another url which I don't want to be redirected but it is being redirected.

```
/customer/my_info_verify
```

What rule needs to be added so that only fully matching url is being redirected?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `=` modifier to define an exact match of URI and location. If an exact match is found, the search terminates.

```
location = /customer/my_info {
  proxy_pass http://example.com/abc;
}
```

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Comment: Keep in mind that this will not match `/customer/my_info/`. If you wanted to match that URL as well, I'd use a regex match like so: `location ~* ^/customer/my_info/?$`